# Pulling in all SSNs with a certain city and state in an Excel table

Tags: excel

I think the solution here is an array formula, but I'm not familiar with those and thought I'd ask before trying to learn.

I have a large table with personal information including city and state. I am creating, on a separate tab, a drop down where you can select city and state, and it pulls in the names and SSNs of all the people who match that city and state. I was able to create the drop down, but I don't know what formula to put in the SSN column of this table so that all SSNs appear based on the cities and states selected in the drop down.

For instance, if I chose New York in the City and State drop downs, I want to produce a list that shows 00000001...Jane Doe, 000000002...John Smith neatly in the table without having to do any work manually.

Let's say the data is on a tab name 'Data' with SSNs in column A, Names in column B, States in column C and Cities in column D.

** Disclaimer, it's not actually cities, states and SSNs that I'm using, but I thought it was a simple example. **

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code here.

Comment: My hope is to do this without code, just using built-in Excel formulas.